# Windows Server 2003 Terminal Services - How to redirect only specific printers?

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2 Terminal Services
Windows XP end user desktops

What's the best way to to only redirect specific printers in a Terminal Services session?

How can I redirect only the "default" printer or only one or two specific printers?

If an end user desktop has 10 or 20 printers installed on their desktop I don't want all of those printers redirected in the Terminal Services session. I would prefer GPO or any setting which would only redirect their desktop default printer or one or two specific printers.

I haven't seen a way to do this in GPO or Terminal Services configuration or in the Remote Desktop Client settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registry key RedirectDefaultPrinterOnly allows redirection of the client's "default" printer only.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default\AddIns\RDPDR

Add a DWORD value: RedirectDefaultPrinterOnly = 1
Deactivate with 0

Source:
http://www.handbook.dk/redirect-only-the-default-printer-in-terminal-services-53.htm

Answer (score 0):

Any printers which drivers are not installed on the terminal server will not loop back. I'm not sure of a way to choose which printers are mapped!
Sorry!